# Dynamically apply search filter on js data using vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-filter

I have a array list which contains column names. I want to write a search filter which will dynamically pick the value from the array and display all the rows and column. Search Filter should be with array contains column names.

Column name can be set dynamically

I have written code like below
Inside script tag

Its not working.. udata value is comming as array

```
export default {
    el: '#apicall',
    mixins: [Vue2Filters.mixin],
    data()
    {
    return {
    toggle: false,
    userData: [],
    search: "",
    apidata: ['Id', 'Name', 'Version'],
    currentvalue: '',
    }
    computed:
    {
    filteruserData: function(){
    var self = this;
    var list =[];

    return this.userData.filter((udata) => {

    for(var i in self.apidata)
    {
    list.push(udata[self.apidata[i]])
    }
    return list.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.search.toLowerCase()) != -1
    });
    },
```

Comment: Write some code please.

Comment: I have added the code... Please check

Comment: I want to use search operation for specific column like apidata

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really get exactly what you need. From what I understood you need to search for column name in `apidata` array using a filter. If your search filter find an element of your `apidata` array, you want to diplay the row values corresponding to column name your search filter found. 
From elements you gave in your post, I don't understand what value you need to diplay and where are they supposed to come from.

Anyway, here is my try to help you. 
Lets suppose that you have a `data` object that contains the row value to display.
The code below search inside the `apidata` array and diplay the value of the corrsponding attribute of the `data` object if anything has been found.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app"><searchCompoenent :data="data"></searchCompoenent></div>
</template>

<script>
import searchCompoenent from "./components/searchComponent.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      data: {
        Id: [1, 9, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        Name: ["name1", "name2"],
        Version: ["2.0", "1.0.0", "1.1-beta"]
      }
    };
  },
  components: {
    searchCompoenent
  }
};
</script>
```

**searchComponent.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="search" placeholder="Search..." type="text" />
    <button type="button" @click="searchColumn">Search!</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      search: "",
      apidata: ["Id", "Name", "Version"]
    };
  },
  props: ["data"],
  methods: {
    searchColumn() {
      let result = this.apidata.find(element => {
        return element === this.search;
      });
      if (result !== undefined) {
        console.log(result);
        console.log(this.data);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```